# Why this alertView does not generate and causes the application to crash?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to know what is wrong with my code, or what is missing in my code. Here is my scenario:

I have a ListView and a CustomAdapter for its data derived from BaseAdapter.

I've made a custom view for each item.

In this custom view ( aka the cell ) I have applied the longClickListener. On pressing the cell for long time, the method of long click gets called successfully. No problems till here.

But the moment I add the code for generating an AlertDialog in this method, the AlterDialog will never generate and crash the whole application.

I tried creating another method outside in the class which now holds the alertDialog generation. Then I call this outside method from the longClickListener's interface method. But still the same crash.

Then I tried creating the whole alertDialog via a Runnable and started the Runnable after 1 second via a Handler, still the alertDialog never generates and causes the application  to crash.

Following is the code till now:

```
void called()
    {
        Handler h = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d("mx", "about to run!");
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FolderCell.this.getContext());
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setTitle("title")
                    .setMessage("message")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
            }
        };

        h.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("mx", "Long clicked!");

        this.called();

        return true;
    }
```

Crash Log:

```
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:589)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at com.rdmteq.pic_measure.FolderCell$2.run(FolderCell.java:216)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-23 23:40:39.734: E/AndroidRuntime(32390):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Additional Info on where the FolderCell is in the heirarchy

```
MainActivity (Activity Class)
    |
    contains--> ListView (ListView Class)
            |
            --> CustomAdapter (BaseAdapter Class) and set to ListView
                   |                    
                   contains-> FolderCell (RelativeLayout Class) generated in getView(..)
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: make sure you are passing currently running Activity Context to `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor

Comment: I tried passing the context from application by passing a reference till the cell. And I also tried passing the context for the cell. But still crashing...

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `FolderCell.this` instead of `FolderCell.this.getContext()`
And check if this will be work in main thread.

Comment: FolderCell.this makes it an error. And the program doesn't compile.

Comment: 'FolderCell.this' - is a main class? Could you give all class code?

Comment: I've edited my question to further show the details of where the FolderCell is contained.

Comment: Hmmm... really weird.
Maybe you can try do something like this:
- put into FolderCell - MainActivity context (and this context try use for creating dialog)
- if this will not work - try:
((Activity)your_main_activity_context).createDialogMethod() 
and createDialogMethod() - this is MainActivity class function where you should put code from 'called'

Comment: CreateDialog function: [get code from here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Tried everything, but the only thing that works is keeping the AlertView  creation method in the mainActivity and then calling this method from the folderCell. I'm not happy with such output, because it breaks the object oriented concept.. On the other hand thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an `AlertDialog` from a thread that is not the UI thread.

To do what you want, you have to use a `Handler` or an `AsyncTask` (show the `AlertDialog` on the `onPostExecute()` method. In my opinion, the `AsyncTask` way is easier.